# How can I apply models to predict the output of a test dataset using SAS?

Tags: predictive-models, sas

I'm trying to use SAS from more of a machine learning perspective than a pure stats perspective. I want to perform resampling on a dataset to measure the predictive accuracy of a LDA and Logistic Regression. However, when I perform `proc logistic` or `proc discrim` all SAS seems to output is a bunch of statistical measures. I want to use the models to predict the output of my test dataset. Is there any way to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.4 in the SAS course notes on *[Multivariate Statistical Methods: Practical Research Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=zR1UPwAACAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions)* there are examples for empirical validation and scoring.

You'd want to consider using the testlist or testout options for example using proc discrim

> proc discrim data = old-data testdata = new-data testlist;
>   class variabls;
>   priors priors;
>   var variables;
>   run;

or

> proc discrim data = old-data testdata = new-data testout = scored-data;
>   class variable;
>   priors priors;
>   var variables;
>   run;

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the OUTPUT statements on both those PROCs, and also look at the SCORE statement, for using a model on new data. More on SCORE from SAS: http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/da/new/801ce/stat/chap4/sect11.htm